# Error al leer un fichero en java con FileInputStream

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio en el que tengo que copiar una imagen en otro fichero byte a byte y verificar que efectivamente son iguales.
El problema es que una vez realizo la copia cuando quiero leer los dos archivos y compararlos no lee el fichero original.

Este es mi código:

```
public class Ejercicio1Streams {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    String fichero="F:\\acceso a datos\\Ejercicio1Streams\\src\\ejercicio1streams\\Cisco_Modulo_1.png";
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fichero);
    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(fichero+" Copia");
    boolean distinto=false;
    
    int c;
    int b;
    try {
        while((c=in.read())!=-1){
            out.write(c);
        }
        
        FileInputStream copia=new FileInputStream(fichero+" Copia");
        while(((b=copia.read())!=-1)&&((c=in.read())!=-1)){
            System.out.println(b+" "+c);
            if(c!=b){
                distinto=true;
            }
        }
        if(distinto==true){
            System.out.println("Son distintos");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Son iguales");
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        copia.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ejercicio1Streams.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: El input stream está "gastado", necesitarías recrearlo porque cuando intentas obtener datos de él después de hacer la copia siempre estará "apuntando" al final del fichero (EOF) y devolverá -1. Además, deberías cerrar el FOS una vez terminada la copia para forzar un "flush" del stream y que el fichero tenga todos los datos